# How to display recent posts in the front-page.php (Home) in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I know that traditionally you can have 2 main pages: the static page (`front-page.php`)and the page for the last posts(`home.php`).

Right now, front-page.php (Home) is my "index" page. It has some content (like a tagline), but now I want my last post to be displayed bellow that content.

**Like this (front-page.php):**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Front Page
*/

get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>  <--this is the tagline of my main page
    <div class="line2"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

 <<<<<<MY LAST POST HERE>>>>>>

    </div><!-- #content -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `get_posts()` and do a basic loop to output the title, content or whatever you like, it will work just like a regular loop, for example..

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Front Page
*/

get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>  <--this is the tagline of my main page
    <div class="line2"></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<!-- Start latest post -->

<?php $latest_post = get_posts( 'numberposts=1' ); // Defaults args fetch posts starting with the most recent ?>
<?php foreach( $latest_post as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?><br />
    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<!-- End latest post -->

    </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Reference for functions used in the above.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Hope that helps.. :)